# Querying all Hibernate Envers revisions between two dates

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have just started using Hibernate Envers for audit, and i will like to know if there is a way to get all the revisions of a class between two dates.

up until now i was using:

```
AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(MYCLASS.class, false, true);
query.add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().le(reader.getRevisionNumberForDate(MYDATE)));
```

to get the revisions of a particular date, but is there a way to recover all the revisions between for example: MYDATE1 and MYDATE2?

Comment: Don't you have method like `AuditEntity.revisionNumber().between("field",MYDATE1,MYDATE2)`?

Comment: what is `AuditEntity`?

Comment: @user1372488 its a class in Hibernate Envers (`org.hibernate.envers.query.AuditEntity`) like we use `Restrictions` in Hibernate.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `between` method of `AuditProperty` to Apply a "between" constraint.

http://docs.jboss.org/envers/api-new/org/hibernate/envers/query/criteria/AuditProperty.html

Answer (score 4):

If you have a timestamp property on your @RevisionEntity you can use a query like this:

```
    List<Object[]> revisions = (List<Object[]>) getAuditReader().createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(MYCLASS.class, false, true)
                .add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("timestamp").gt(startDate))
                .add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("timestamp").lt(endDate))
                .getResultList();
```